# Row and Column Dimensions in Python - Newbie question

Tags: python, loops, row

Please, can somebody confirm me, if the first statement below is ok and if it is possible to use a similar loop for width?

Many thanks.

```
for i in range(6, row + 1, +1):
    sheet.row_dimensions[i].height = 15.75


sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 20
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 20
sheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = 20
sheet.column_dimensions['D'].width = 20
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in range(ord('A'), ord('D') + 1):
    sheet.column_dimensions[i].width = 20
```

OR

```
for i in 'ABCD':
    sheet.column_dimensions[i].width = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for c in ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:
    sheet.column_dimensions[c].width = 20
```

This should do it.

Comment: What if its `A` - `Z`?

Comment: it is not. But should be from string import ascii_lowercase then for c in ascii_lowercase: sheet.column_dimensions[c.upper()].width = 20

Comment: How do you know it is not? What if the OP just gave a MRE? And what if it’s A - Y? Your solution also needs an additional import.